# Disconnect a node from graph

Tags: algorithm, graph, hashmap, directed-graph, defaultdict

Given a graph and two nodes. Minimum set of nodes one need to remove to disconnect two nodes From each other.

```
sample input:

graph node connection
2->9
7->2
7->9
9->5

node to disconnect
7
9

answer is:
2,7
```

There are two paths from 7 -> 9 one is [ 7, 2, 9 ] and other is [ 7, 9 ].
First i build a function to find all posible paths, which gives above paths.

```
from collections import defaultdict

graph=defaultdict(list)
for i in range(int(input())):
    a,b=[int(x) for x in input().split()]
    graph[a].append(b)

def find_path(graph, start, end, path=[]):
        path = path + [start]
        if start == end:
            return [path]
        if not graph.get(start):
            return []
        paths=[]
        for node in graph[start]:
            if node not in path:
                newpaths = find_path(graph, node, end, path)
                for newpath in newpaths:
                    paths.append(newpath)

        return paths

node1=int(input())
node2=int(input())

k=find_path(graph,node1,node2)

arr=[]
for path in k:
    arr.append(path[-2])
print(*arr)
```

after finding all posible paths I simply removed the second last nodes from all possible path which gives me min nodes to remove but it was partially correct.
Then I thought do intersection of two paths to remove common, if there is no common then just remove second last one.
But no progress so far.
Please help me understand where I am making mistake.

Comment: Try looking into minimum cut - maximal flow, it should help you out.

Comment: Why answer is not just node 7? if there`s no destination node, no path can possibly reach it